# How update DATA on realtime without click or submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need update data in table without a action send click or submit. For example, when i change input value, i would like save in real time this changes in the database.

My question is, how i can compare if have changes in the form?
I read this post, [Submitting data without clicking a submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370756/submitting-data-without-clicking-a-submit-button), but here, the function  is executed every 5s, and i need save just only have changes.

HTML

```
 <form id="formos" method="">
 Status:<input type="text" class="form-control uppercase" form="">
 </form>
```

JS

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(e){
    if($('#formos').serialize()!=$('#formos').data('serialize'))return true;
    else e=null; // i.e; if form state change show box not.
});
```

Comment: are you asking for architecture or code?

Comment: Subscribe change event on your UI, use socket.io or (better) narrow down your problem and post some code.

Comment: Put the AJAX call into the `change` event handler.

Comment: You can set event listener on `keydown` or `keyup` and then send request  on preferred situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I do it is like this. I send the data via ajax on keystroke. But I do it with a timeout of 300ms so that it won't send on each keystroke only when they stopped typing.

I then check on the server side if there was a change, if not I do nothing, if there was already an entry I update, if there was no entry I insert. Simple.

If you are having trouble with the code I can provide some.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="test_1" />
<input type="text" id="test_2" />
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').keyup(function(){
        var elem = $(this);
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
            sendValue(elem.attr('id'), elem.val());
        }, 300));
    });
    $('input[type=text]').change(function(){
        sendValue($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
    });
});

function sendValue(key, value) {
    $.post('path/to/script.php', {key: key, value: value}, function(data, result){
        if(result == 'success') {
            console.log('Data was sent');
        } else {
            console.log('AJAX post failed');
        }
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
$key = $_POST['key']; //just remember never to just receive input from a user, first check if it is something valid and not something trying to hack you
$value = $_POST['value'];
//then check if there is a difference of value to what you had
//insert or update in your db accordingly
die(); //die if you are using a controller within a framework, if you do not it will send back all the other stuff with it
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx Chris... His is exactly what I need.
Would you care to have something for me to start ?

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren I updated my answer with some code

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren I am glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is sufficient to update once the field loses focus and you use text fields, you can use the following

```
$(document).on("blur", input, function() {
  var changedValue = $(this).val();
  // Store changedValue in database using Ajax
});
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simplified way of doing this would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $('#content').load('data.php');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Basically, what would happen is the web page would pull a request from that specific "**data.php**" script every **5** seconds and load it into the `#content` element accordingly.

On your **data.php** page, you would have a script, something along the lines of:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = 'something'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $output = $row['yourrow'];
    echo $output . <br>;
}
```

And inside of your HTML:

```
<div id="content">
 <!-- inside here is where the output code from the data.php
 page would be displayed. !-->
</div>
```

Of course, you'd substitute `#content` with the actual ID of the element you are using, along with tailoring all of the other code to your needs.

Comment: thx Caelan, but i need inverse this. I need when change input, or one select for exemple, update data automatically a database.  send request and require ajax i know. I can try send only have changes in the form...